# Changing between front and back camera in Unity using Vuforia and Fungus

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am new to both Unity and Vuforia.

I have been trying to figure out how to change between the two camera modes in Vuforia by using a UI button.

So what I am trying to achieve is being able to change between front and back camera while the app is running.

I have linked the following script to the UI button with its build-in OnClickEvent in Unity, but it doesn't seem to work since DebugLog messages are not being written either.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class CameraSwap : MonoBehaviour {

    bool cameramode = false;
    public void OnCameraChangeMode()
    {
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection currentDir = Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraDirection();
        if (!cameramode)
        {
            RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
            Debug.Log("Using FRONT Camera");
        }
        else
        {
            RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
            Debug.Log("Using BAC Camera");
        }
    }

    private void RestartCamera(Vuforia.CameraDevice.CameraDirection newDir)
    {
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Init(newDir);
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the inspector for the gameobject where you set this as the callback for OnClick.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e5158d8a4eb80dc0c5664e9bb54f1bdf and here is link to the project if its any help:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rS4cmxc85FOXiTez9Vib1Qo7QY8Qdm5U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you're not calling anything with that inspector, note that it says "No Function".

Comment: I tried to add the function (string) to it but seems like I lack the required Unity skills to make it work since I cant get it working.

Comment: eh your cameramode bool is never switched from false to true?

Answer (score 0):

The advice here is correct - just select it from the available functions. [image]

For those who have struggled to do a camera flipping script with Unity/Vuforia, here is a working example of the entire script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;


public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool lightOn = false;
    private bool frontCamera = false;

    public void CameraChange()
    {
        if (!frontCamera)
        {
            RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
            frontCamera = true;
            Debug.Log("Using Front Camera");
        }
        else if (frontCamera)
        {
            RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
            frontCamera = false;
            Debug.Log("Using Back Camera");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera status available.");
        }
    } 

    private void RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection newDir)
    {
        CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
        CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
        CameraDevice.Instance.Init(newDir);
        CameraDevice.Instance.Start();

        // These are to fight the bug the will otherwise flip the selfie cam upside down on iOS
        // Periodically check to see if still needed
        VuforiaUnity.OnPause();
        VuforiaUnity.OnResume();
    }
}
```